# Remove a row of table based on two data

Tags: php, jquery, duplicates

I'm trying to delete duplicated entry from an array to then display it in a table.

Here is an example of the data format I use :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'Statut' => string 'REFUSED' (length=5)
      'Username' => string 'name' (length=4)
      'Nom' => string 'firstname' (length=9)
      'Email' => string 'mail@gmail.com' (length=14)
      'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'Statut' => string 'REFUSED' (length=5)
      'Username' => string 'name' (length=4)
      'Nom' => string 'firstname' (length=9)
      'Email' => string 'mail@gmail.com' (length=14)
      'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'Statut' => string 'VALID' (length=5)
      'Username' => string 'name' (length=12)
      'Nom' => string 'firstname' (length=19)
      'Email' => string 'mail@gmail.com' (length=14)
      'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      'Statut' => string 'VALID' (length=5)
      'Username' => string 'user2' (length=10)
      'Nom' => string 'second_nae' (length=8)
      'Email' => string 'othermail@gmail.com' (length=27)
      'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
```

Right now I manage to delete duplicate with some Jquery based on if I already saw the email somewhere.

Here is the HTML part :

```
  <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th id="Statut">Statut</th>
     <th id="Username">Username</th>
     <th id="Nom">Nom</th>
     <th id="Email">Email</th>
     <th id="Regularisation">Regularisation</th>        
    </tr>
  </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
                        <td class="statut">REFUSED</td>
                        <td class="username">name</td>
                        <td class="nom">firstname</td>
                        <td class="mail">mail@gmail.com</td>
                        <td class="regularisation">N</td>
        </tr><tr class="row">
                        <td class="statut">REFUSED</td>
                        <td class="username">name</td>
                        <td class="nom">firstname</td>
                        <td class="mail">mail@gmail.fr</td>
                        <td class="regularisation">N</td>
       </tr><tr class="row">
                        <td class="statut">VALID</td>
                        <td class="username">name</td>
                        <td class="nom">firstname</td>
                        <td class="mail">mail@gmail.com</td>
                        <td class="regularisation">N</td>
        </tr><tr class="row">
                        <td class="statut">VALID</td>
                        <td class="username">user2</td>
                        <td class="nom">second_nae</td>
                        <td class="mail">othermail@gmail.com</td>
                        <td class="regularisation">N</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And JS doing the work :

```
var seen = {};
$('.mail').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).parent().remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

After JS, the HTML will look like this :

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th id="Statut">Statut</th>
         <th id="Username">Username</th>
         <th id="Nom">Nom</th>
         <th id="Email">Email</th>
         <th id="Regularisation">Regularisation</th>        
        </tr>
      </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                            <td class="statut">REFUSED</td>
                            <td class="username">name</td>
                            <td class="nom">firstname</td>
                            <td class="mail">mail@gmail.com</td>
                            <td class="regularisation">N</td>
            </tr><tr class="row">
                            <td class="statut">VALID</td>
                            <td class="username">user2</td>
                            <td class="nom">second_nae</td>
                            <td class="mail">othermail@gmail.com</td>
                            <td class="regularisation">N</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Problem is using only the mail isn't enough :

If I have two entries with the same mail but with different statut I should keep one of both.

So the example above would be reduce to :

```
array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'Statut' => string 'REFUSED' (length=5)
          'Username' => string 'name' (length=4)
          'Nom' => string 'firstname' (length=9)
          'Email' => string 'mail@gmail.com' (length=14)
          'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'Statut' => string 'VALID' (length=5)
          'Username' => string 'name' (length=12)
          'Nom' => string 'firstname' (length=19)
          'Email' => string 'mail@gmail.com' (length=14)
          'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=5)
          'Statut' => string 'VALID' (length=5)
          'Username' => string 'user2' (length=10)
          'Nom' => string 'second_nae' (length=8)
          'Email' => string 'othermail@gmail.com' (length=27)
          'Regularisation' => string 'N' (length=1)
```

I'm pretty sure I could do it throught DOM navigation but I would like to know if there was any PHP way to do it properly and reduce the array even before displaying it.

Comment: How about showing a snippet that contains the actual HTML?

Comment: HTML snippet added

Comment: I'll take it one level higher, if your data is coming from a database query maybe you can modify the query to not return duplicate entries, and a level higher than that, maybe you can have integrity constraints that would prevent you from inserting those duplicates in the first place.

Comment: The data are coming from a CSV so I can't really edit it at an higher level :/

Comment: Added a working HTML snippet

Comment: So the question is a PHP question and not a JS question. I see. Here is the snippet I meant: https://jsfiddle.net/3d5p699a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php unset function to remove from array, like below:

```
$dataArray = array (
              0 => 
                array (
                  'Statut' => 'REFUSED',
                  'Username' =>  'name',
                  'Nom' =>  'firstname',
                  'Email' =>  'mail@gmail.com' ,
                  'Regularisation' =>  'N' ,
                 ),
              1 => 
                array (
                  'Statut' =>  'REFUSED' ,
                  'Username' =>  'name' ,
                  'Nom' =>  'firstname' ,
                  'Email' =>  'mail@gmail.com' ,
                  'Regularisation' =>  'N',
                 ),
              2 => 
                array (
                  'Statut' =>  'VALID', 
                  'Username' =>  'name', 
                  'Nom' =>  'firstname',
                  'Email' =>  'mail@gmail.com', 
                  'Regularisation' =>  'N' ,
                 ),
              3 => 
                array (
                  'Statut' =>  'VALID' ,
                  'Username' =>  'user2' ,
                  'Nom' =>  'second_nae' ,
                  'Email' =>  'othermail@gmail.com', 
                  'Regularisation' =>  'N' ,
                 ),       
            );    

foreach($dataArray as $key => $val)
{
    foreach($dataArray as $k => $v)
    {
        if($key != $k && $val['Email'] == $v['Email'] && $val['Statut'] == $v['Statut'] ) //here you can add multiple keys 
        {
            unset($dataArray[$key]);
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($dataArray);
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Statut] => REFUSED
            [Username] => name
            [Nom] => firstname
            [Email] => mail@gmail.com
            [Regularisation] => N
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Statut] => VALID
            [Username] => name
            [Nom] => firstname
            [Email] => mail@gmail.com
            [Regularisation] => N
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Statut] => VALID
            [Username] => user2
            [Nom] => second_nae
            [Email] => othermail@gmail.com
            [Regularisation] => N
        )

)
```

Comment: Great :) glad to help you dear @Nirnae

Answer (score 0):

Check it with PHP.

```
$newarray = array();  // create the new array to store the email, status combo

foreach($userData as $k=>$v)
{
   $ele = $v['Email'].'::'.$v['Statut'];

   if(in_array($ele,$newarray ))
      unset($userData[$k]);    // remove the element whose email and status existed already

   array_push($v['Email'].'::'.$v['Statut']);  // push every new email , status in the new array to check further
}
```